# Can't get the ACM references in my document

Tags: bibliographies, acm

I use ACM reference style but in the reference section I do not get the references list. also, in the text, I get question mark in the citation. I downloaded the following file for the reference style:

> ACM-Reference-Format-Journals

from ACM website: https://www.acm.org/publications/acm-latex-style-guide

This is my .tex minimal script which includes one citation:

```
% TEMPLATE for Usenix papers, specifically to meet requirements of
%  USENIX '05
% originally a template for producing IEEE-format articles using LaTeX.
%   written by Matthew Ward, CS Department, Worcester Polytechnic Institute.
% adapted by David Beazley for his excellent SWIG paper in Proceedings,
%   Tcl 96
% turned into a smartass generic template by De Clarke, with thanks to
%   both the above pioneers
% use at your own risk.  Complaints to /dev/null.
% make it two column with no page numbering, default is 10 point

% Munged by Fred Douglis <douglis@research.att.com> 10/97 to separate
% the .sty file from the LaTeX source template, so that people can
% more easily include the .sty file into an existing document.  Also
% changed to more closely follow the style guidelines as represented
% by the Word sample file. 

% Note that since 2010, USENIX does not require endnotes. If you want
% foot of page notes, don't include the endnotes package in the 
% usepackage command, below.


% This version uses the latex2e styles, not the very ancient 2.09 stuff.
\documentclass[letterpaper,twocolumn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{textcomp}


\begin{document}

%don't want date printed
\date{}

%make title bold and 14 pt font (Latex default is non-bold, 16 pt)
\title{\Large \bf Test}

%for single author (just remove % characters)
\author{
{\rm Your N.\ Here}\\
Your Institution
\and
{\rm Second Name}\\
Second Institution
% copy the following lines to add more authors
% \and
% {\rm Name}\\
%Name Institution
} % end author

\maketitle

% Use the following at camera-ready time to suppress page numbers.
% Comment it out when you first submit the paper for review.
\thispagestyle{empty}


\subsection*{Abstract}

\section{Introduction}
testing\endnote{ss} abstract \cite{spielberger2010test}


{\footnotesize \bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format-Journals}
\bibliography{references}}
\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

Also, this is the ref.bib file:

```
%%
%% WinShell 3.3.2.6
%% http://www.winshell.org/
%%

% Strings


% Preamble


% BibTeX Entries
@book{spielberger2010test,
  title={Test anxiety inventory},
  author={Spielberger, Charles D},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
```

Can you please help identify the source of the problem? why I can not get the in-text citation or the references list?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you run BibTeX in between runs of `pdflatex`?

Comment: Do the filenames match? In your `.tex` file, you have `\bibliography{references}` but you write that the bib file is called `ref.bib` whereas it should be `references.bib`. I don't have the ACM references BibTeX style here, thus I cannot test it right now.